# html table reactivity to resizing

Tags: javascript, css

How do I determined HTML table reactivity to it content when resizing that is I want to know if a table has reach it minimum squish so as to hide a table column just like jquery datable

Comment: as long as here is not a free coding service, it's a good practice to provide the code you have already tried and ask for help on that. providing more details would help others to better understand and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

i'm strongly recomended you learn about css media query,for knowing "when" to resize/hide you need to know screensize resolution and css media query its about that , https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: I know how to use media queries but jquery datatable determine minimum squish before hiding the column that's what I want to know how its done